# Jquery form validation is not working properly

Tags: jquery, html

My code problem is the validation is working not properly i.e; if we enter the first name,it is showing the error message "the name should be 3 characters" but it is not disable the submit button same as all the fields are showing the error messages but it is submitted successfully.so help me it is submitted only when all the validation are correct.i am writing the code properly but i will not understand where is the problem it is.

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
        <style>
            @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Signika');
    
            .nopadding {
                padding: 0px;
            }
    
            .align {
                margin-left: 50%;
            }
    
            .inputtop {
                font-family: 'Signika', sans-serif;
                margin-top: 10px;
            }
    
            .signup {
                font-family: 'Signika', sans-serif;
                text-align: center;
                color: #31d3fb;
                font-size: 50px;
                height: 50px;``
            }
    
            .set {
                padding-right: 0px;
                padding-left: 0px;
            }
    
            .copyright {
                margin-top: 33px;
            }
    
            .panel-primary {
                border-color: #fff;
            }
    
            .panel-primary>.panel-heading {
                background: #bce8f1;
            }
    
            .panel-primary>.panel-body {
                background-color: #fff;
            }
        </style>
    
    
    </head>
    
    
    <div>
        <div class="col-md-7 nopadding color">
            <img src="images/energywallpaper2.jpg" width="100%" height="920px" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 color">
    
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <h1 class="signup">Signup</h1>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form name="myform" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="fname">First Name *</label>
                            <input id="fname" name="fname" class="form-control" type="text" data-validation="required">
                            <span id="error_name" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="lname">Last Name *</label>
                            <input id="lname" name="lname" class="form-control" type="text" data-validation="email">
                            <span id="error_lname" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email">Email *</label>
                            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-control">
                            <span id="error_email" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
    
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password">Password *</label>
                            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control">
                            <span id="error_password" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password">Confirm password *</label>
                            <input type="password" id="cpassword" name="cpassword" class="form-control">
                            <span id="error_cpassword" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="disc">Private Notes</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" col="50"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="disc">Visible Notes</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" col="50"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="dob">Date Of Birth *</label>
                            <input type="text" name="dob" id="dob" class="form-control">
                            <span id="error_dob" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <button id="submit" type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary center">Submit</button>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    
                        <div class="separator">
                            <p class="change_link">Already a member ?
                                <a href="#signin" class="to_register"> Log in </a>
                            </p>
    
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            <br />
    
                            <div>
                                <p class="copyright">AMK website©2017 All Rights Reserved.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
    
                </div>
                </form>
    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("#dob").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
            yearRange: "-90:+00"
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $flag = 1;
            $("#fname").focusout(function() {
    
                if ($(this).val() == '') {
                    $(this).css("border-color", "#FF0000");
                    $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
                    $("#error_name").text("* You have to enter your first name!");
                } else if ($(this).val().length < 3) {
                    $(this).css("border-color", "#FF0000");
                    $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
                    $("#error_name").text("*You have to enter minimum 3 characters of your first name!");
                } else {
                    $(this).css("border-color", "#2eb82e");
                    $('#submit').attr('disabled', false);
                    $("#error_name").text("");
    
                }
            });
            $("#lname").focusout(function() {
                if ($(this).val() == '') {
                    $(this).css("border-color", "#FF0000");
                    $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
                    $("#error_lname").text("* You have to enter your Last name!");
                } else if ($(this).val().length < 3) {
    
                    $(this).css("border-color", "#FF0000");
                    $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
                    $("#error_lname").text("*You have to enter minimum 3 characters of your last name!");
                } else {
                    $(this).css("border-color", "#2eb82e");
                    $('#submit').attr('disabled', false);
                    $("#error_lname").text("");
                }
            });
            $("#dob").focusout(function() {
                if ($(this).val() == 'null') {
                    $(this).css("border-color", "#FF0000");
                    $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
                    $("#error_dob").text("* You have to enter your Date of Birth!");
                } else {
                    $(this).css("border-color", "#2eb82e");
                    $('#submit').attr('disabled', false);
                    $("#error_dob").text("");
                }
            });
    
            $("#email").focusout(function() {
                var email = $("#email").val();
                var pattern = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/
    
                if ($(this).val() == "") {
                    $(this).css("border-color", "#FF0000");
                    $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
                    $("#error_email").text("* You have to enter your email!");
                } else if (!pattern.test(email)) {
                    $(this).css("border-color", "#FF0000");
                    $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
                    $("#error_email").text("* Please enter valid email");
                } else {
                    console.log("success");
                    $(this).css({
                        "border-color": "#2eb82e"
                    });
                    $('#submit').attr('disabled', false);
                    $("#error_email").text("");
    
                }
            });
            $("#password").focusout(function() {
                var pass = $("#password").val();
                var strength = 0;
                //if password contains both lower and uppercase characters, increase strength value
                if (pass.match(/([a-z].*[A-Z])|([A-Z].*[a-z])/)) strength += 1
    
                //if it has numbers and characters, increase strength value
                if (pass.match(/([a-zA-Z])/) && pass.match(/([0-9])/)) strength += 1
    
                //if it has one special character, increase strength value
                if (pass.match(/([!,%,&,@,#,$,^,*,?,_,~])/)) strength += 1
    
                //if it has two special characters, increase strength value
                if (pass.match(/(.*[!,%,&,@,#,$,^,*,?,_,~].*[!,%,&,@,#,$,^,*,?,_,~])/)) strength += 1
    
                if (pass == '') {
                    //console.log("test" + strength)
                    $(this).css("border-color", "#FF0000");
                    $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
                    $("#error_password").text("* You have to enter your password !");
                } else if ($("#password").val().length < 8) {
                    $(this).css("border-color", "#FF0000");
                    $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
                    $("#error_password").text("*You have to enter minimum 8 characters of your password !");
                } else if (strength < 1) {
                    $(this).css("border-color", "#FF0000");
                    $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
                    $("#error_password").text("*your password is weak!please use letters,special symbols and numbers");
                } else {
                    $(this).css({
                        "border-color": "#2eb82e"
                    });
                    $('#submit').attr('disabled', false);
                    $("#error_password").text("");
                }
            });
            $("#cpassword").focusout(function() {
                cpass = $("#cpassword").val();
                if (cpass == '') {
                    $(this).css("border-color", "#FF0000");
                    $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
                    $("#error_cpassword").text("* You have to re-enter your password !");
                } else {
                    $(this).css({
                        "border-color": "#2eb82e"
                    });
                    $('#submit').attr('disabled', false);
                    $("#error_cpassword").text("");
                }
    
            });
    
            $("#submit").click(function() {
                if ($("#fname").val() == '') {
                    $("#fname").css("border-color", "#FF0000");
                    $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
                    $("#error_name").text("* You have to enter your first name!");
                }
                if ($("#lname").val() == '') {
                    $("#lname").css("border-color", "#FF0000");
                    $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
                    $("#error_lname").text("* You have to enter your Last name!");
                }
                if ($("#dob").val() == '') {
                    $("#dob").css("border-color", "#FF0000");
                    $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
                    $("#error_dob").text("* You have to enter your Date of Birth!");
                }
                if ($("#email").val() == '') {
                    $("#email").css("border-color", "#FF0000");
                    $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
                    $("#error_email").text("* You have to enter your email!");
                }
                if ($("#password").val() == '') {
                    $("#password").css("border-color", "#FF0000");
                    $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
                    $("#error_password").text("* You have to enter your password!");
                }
                if ($("#cpassword").val() == '') {
                    $("#cpassword").css("border-color", "#FF0000");
                    $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
                    $("#error_cpassword").text("* You have to re-enter your password!");
                }
            });
    
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If validation fails, you need to return false at the end of the click function for the submit button. This will prevent the form from submitting.

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
        var passedValidation = true;
        if ($("#fname").val() == '') {
            $("#fname").css("border-color", "#FF0000");
            $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
            $("#error_name").text("* You have to enter your first name!");
            passedValidation = false;
        }
        if ($("#lname").val() == '') {
            $("#lname").css("border-color", "#FF0000");
            $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
            $("#error_lname").text("* You have to enter your Last name!");
            passedValidation = false;
        }
        if ($("#dob").val() == '') {
            $("#dob").css("border-color", "#FF0000");
            $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
            $("#error_dob").text("* You have to enter your Date of Birth!");
            passedValidation = false;
        }
        if ($("#email").val() == '') {
            $("#email").css("border-color", "#FF0000");
            $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
            $("#error_email").text("* You have to enter your email!");
            passedValidation = false;
        }
        if ($("#password").val() == '') {
            $("#password").css("border-color", "#FF0000");
            $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
            $("#error_password").text("* You have to enter your password!");
            passedValidation = false;
        }
        if ($("#cpassword").val() == '') {
            $("#cpassword").css("border-color", "#FF0000");
            $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
            $("#error_cpassword").text("* You have to re-enter your password!");
            passedValidation = false;
        }

        return passedValidation;
    });
```

Also, in your validation checks for the password, you don't confirm that both passwords match up.

Comment: Thanks ItsDuckyyyy,the submit button working only  when the values are empty but my problem is when first name should be 3 characters but we entered 2 characters and submit it is submitted.this condition write in the focus out function,when less than 3 character the submit button should disabled otherwise enabled. but it is not working,please look into the   $("#fname").focusout(function()) and i confirm the both passwords match up in this focusout function.not only first name it is applicable all the fields

Comment: I'm not quite sure what's not working for you @Allu, it appears to work for me (see: [here](https://puu.sh/xqQCw/d411690af4.gif)).

Comment: Thank you duckkyyyy.now i understand the problem of mycode

Answer (score 0):

you have to change the data-validation="text" for

```
 `<input id="fname" name="fname" class="form-control" type="text" data-validation="required">`
```